# Single app mode enterprise app update

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise, mdm, in-house-distribution

I have kiosk application installed on iPad in Supervised ASAM mode. I am shipping/installing this iPad to my customer’s site. This way customer can use only my kiosk application. I am distributing my app using Enterprise Distribution Process.

Now I want to update my application in all those iPads. I want to update the app in such a way that it don’t show popup for update. I want to force update my application in background that does’t require user input.

How can i do that?

Can I programmatically call for an update to an enterprise app installed via mdm in the background? Or is this something I have to push through the MDM and can't be called on from an app within the iPad?

Comment: As far as I know it is a feature of MDM system. If this is the case then I'd suggest you to tag the specific MDM that you use and mention it in the question...

Comment: @MichaelKessler I am using jamf cloud for MDM.